# Python 3 : Recursion error throwing NameError ( BST problem)

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I have an issue while running in-order traversal as a method of my class.

```
class BST:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.left=None
        self.right=None

    def insert(self,data):
        if self.data < data:
            #insert right
            if self.right is None:
                self.right = BST(data)
            else:
                insert(self.right, data)
        else:
            if self.left is None:
                self.left = BST(data)
            else:
                insert(self.left,data)

     def inorder(self):
        if self.left:
            inorder(self.left)
        print(self.data)
        if self.right:
            inorder(self.right)


r = BST('50')
r.insert('60')
r.insert('40')
r.inorder()
```

This works fine for insertion. Please note that I haven't used self.insert and just insert for recursion.

The following is my in-order traversal method inside the class BST

```
    def inorder(self):
        if self.left:
            inorder(self.left)
        print(self.data)
        if self.right:
            inorder(self.right)
```

This throws an error saying

```
30 r.insert('60')
     31 r.insert('40')
---> 32 r.inorder()
     33 print(r.right.data)
     34 print(r.left.data)
```

AttributeError: 'BST' object has no attribute 'inorder'.

I tried using self.inorder() and it says it received two arguements, though it was expecting one.

However, if I modify the code from 
inorder(Self.left) to self.left.inorder(), it works fine.

Can someone explain me as to why this happened?
Also, is it important to use self.function_name for recursion calling inside class methods because my insert function works anyway?

Comment: Can you update your code to include the entire class definition in one snippet and then all of the lines where you define `r` and perform operations on it?

Comment: @awarrier99 I have edited the question, can you let me know if I am missing any more details?

Comment: That looks good, but can you also show where you defined the `inorder` function? Is it not part of the class definition?

Comment: Do you have an `insert` function anywhere else in your code? It's impossible to run it like that.

Comment: There are a few issues here that I spot right off the bat. When you are trying to recursively call a class method, you need to call it with the self prefix Ie. `self.method`. Another issue I see is with the variables you are passing in those recursive calls. For example, when you define the `insert` method, you specify a single parameter, but you pass two arguments on the recursive call.

Comment: @Kickin_Wing I think he is trying to replicate a C++ code. That's why all the function calls and the parameters are not correct. But I don't understand how he said "This works fine for insertion." It shouldn't.

Comment: Yes, I recently switched from C to Python

Comment: @Kickin_Wing - Can you explain me as to how insert function is wrong and what should be the correct way?

Comment: @Asocia - Can you tell me why my insert function is wrong? I also tried running it online on IDE and it worked.

Comment: @Kashii what exactly is your code intended to do? Can you provide an example of your expected output?

Comment: @Kickin_Wing - I intend to write a function for in-order traversal inside the class BST. However, when I write my function - def inorder(self) ; if self.left: self.left.inorder() works but if I write def inorder(self) ; if self.left: self.inorder(self.left) it throws an error?
Why can't this inorder function work like the one that I have for insert? 
Would insert function work the same way if I write insert(self.right,data) as self.right.insert(data)? 
What's the difference in both of these styles

Comment: @Kashii Saying `insert(this->right, data)` in C is roughly equivalent to `self.insert(self.right, data)` in python.

Comment: @Asocia - Okay, that makes sense. So why does my insert function work without self keyword, and in-order function is asking for self keyword(indirectly) . I am clear with the fact that for calling instance function inside the class we have to use self keyword. However, my doubt is in the above comment that I have asked Kickin_Wing. It would be really kind of you if you can help me in answering that?

Comment: @Asocia - I am using Jupyter, and it works fine . I have used repl.it and onlinegdb to check the same and my insert function works fine. If you do print(r.left.data) you would see the data

Comment: @Kashii Check [this](https://repl.it/repls/ViolentFocusedAbstraction) and you will see that it fails with insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out using helper functions:

```
class BST:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


def insert(root, bst):
    if root is None:
        root = bst
    else:
        if root.data < bst.data:
            if root.right is None:
                root.right = bst
            else:
                insert(root.right, bst)
        else:
            if root.left is None:
                root.left = bst
            else:
                insert(root.left, bst)


def inorder(root):
    if root:
        inorder(root.left)
        print(root.data)
        inorder(root.right)


r = BST(50)
insert(r, BST(60))
insert(r, BST(40))
inorder(r)
```

If you want to include the helper functions in the class as methods then you can write it this way:

```
class BST:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def insert(self, root, bst):
        if root is None:
            root = bst
        else:
            if root.data < bst.data:
                if root.right is None:
                    root.right = bst
                else:
                    self.insert(root.right, bst)
            else:
                if root.left is None:
                    root.left = bst
                else:
                    self.insert(root.left, bst)

    def inorder(self, root):
        if root:
            self.inorder(root.left)
            print(root.data)
            self.inorder(root.right)


r = BST(50)
r.insert(r, BST(60))
r.insert(r, BST(40))
r.inorder(r)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for. You made by day.